# xcode iOS simulator not showing app but xcode says no errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

Im trying to run my simple app that displays the default orientation and the orientation with respect to the magnetic north both in terms of yaw pitch and roll.  Xcode code says its a successful build but when i go to the simulator it automatically returns me to this screen on Xcode. 
[image]

The simulator is just a black screen.  Heres is all my code which is not very much only one implementation file:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  gyro_test
//
//  Created by USER on 11/20/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 taphappytech. All rights reserved.
//

#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){

}
@property(nonatomic, strong) CMMotionManager *motionManager;

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize motionManager;

@synthesize navPitch;
@synthesize navRoll;
@synthesize navYaw;

@synthesize magPitch;
@synthesize magRoll;
@synthesize magYaw;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    //Start up the CMMotionManager


    motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 60.0;
    //Set the update interval to 60Hz

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)natOrientation:(id)sender {

    [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdates];

    double rRotation = motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.roll*180/M_PI;
    double pRotation = motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.pitch*180/M_PI;
    double yRotation = motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.yaw*180/M_PI;

    NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",yRotation];
    self.navYaw.text = myString;

    myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",pRotation];
    self.navPitch.text = myString;

    myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",rRotation];
    self.navRoll.text = myString;

}

- (IBAction)magOrientation:(id)sender {

    NSOperationQueue *currentQueue = [NSOperationQueue currentQueue];

    [self.motionManager     startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXMagneticNorthZVertical     toQueue:currentQueue withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error)     {NSLog(@"%@",motion.attitude);}];


    double rRotation = motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.roll*180/M_PI;
    double pRotation = motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.pitch*180/M_PI;
    double yRotation = motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.yaw*180/M_PI;

    NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",yRotation];
    self.magYaw.text = myString;

    myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",pRotation];
    self.magPitch.text = myString;

    myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",rRotation];
    self.magRoll.text = myString;

}
@end
```

Why is this app not showing up on the simulator?

Comment: Disable the breakpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a breakpoint enabled in Xcode. Click the little blue bar to the left of the highlighted line of code, then re-run your app.

Breakpoints cause your app to be 'paused' - so that code can be more easily debugged. Since this code is being run at startup, the breakpoint pauses your app before it even loads a view.

Comment: Yes! that was it thanks.  I had no idea a breakpoint would do that or what a breakpoint is for that matter.